# Reading Excel file into R with operator in tab name

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I am reading a file with different tabs into R. However, they changed the tab names so they contain operators now, which R doesnt seem to like. For instance (and this is where the code occurs) "Storico_G1" became "Storico_G+1".

I post the code below, but the error occurs early on. I am basically looking for a workaround/to change the tab names before i create data.frames.

NB I left the code as it was before they changed the tab name from "Storico_G1" to "Storico_G+1" as I think its easier to grasp this way.

Can anybody guide me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(openxlsx)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

Storico_G <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/it/business-servizi/dati-operativi-business/dati_operativi_bilanciamento_sistema/2018/DatiOperativi_2018-IT.xlsx",sheet = "Storico_G", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)

Storico_G1 <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/it/business-servizi/dati-operativi-business/dati_operativi_bilanciamento_sistema/2018/DatiOperativi_2018-IT.xlsx", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)

# Selecting Column C,E,R from Storico_G and stored in variable Storico_G_df
# Selecting Column A,P from Storico_G+1 and stored in variable Storico_G1_df

Storico_G_df <- data.frame(Storico_G$pubblicazione,Storico_G$IMMESSO, Storico_G$`RICONSEGNATO.(1)`, Storico_G$BILANCIAMENTO.RESIDUALE )
Storico_G1_df <- data.frame(Storico_G1$pubblicazione, Storico_G1$`SBILANCIAMENTO.ATTESO.DEL.SISTEMA.(SAS)`)


# Conerting pubblicazione in date format and time
Storico_G_df$pubblicazione <- ymd_h(Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione)
Storico_G1_df$pubblicazione   <- ymd_h(Storico_G1_df$Storico_G1.pubblicazione)


# Selecting on row which is having 4PM value in Storico_G+1 excel sheet tab
Storico_G1_df <- subset(Storico_G1_df, hour(Storico_G1_df$pubblicazione) == 16)
rownames(Storico_G1_df) <- 1:nrow(Storico_G1_df)

# Averaging hourly values to 1 daily data point in G excel sheet tab
Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione <- strptime(Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione, "%Y_%m_%d_%H")
storico_G_df_agg <- aggregate(Storico_G_df, by=list(day=format(Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione, "%F")), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)[,-2]

#cbind.fill function
cbind.fill <- function(...){
    nm <- list(...) 
    nm <- lapply(nm, as.matrix)
    n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
    do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
        rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
}

#cbind with both frames
G_G1_df= data.frame(cbind.fill(storico_G_df_agg,Storico_G1_df))

#keep required columns
keep=c("day", "Storico_G.IMMESSO","Storico_G..RICONSEGNATO..1..","Storico_G1..SBILANCIAMENTO.ATTESO.DEL.SISTEMA..SAS..")

#update dataframe to kept variables
G_G1_df=G_G1_df[,keep,drop=FALSE]

#Rename crazy variable names
G_G1_df <- data.frame(G_G1_df) %>% 
     select(day, Storico_G.IMMESSO, Storico_G..RICONSEGNATO..1.., Storico_G1..SBILANCIAMENTO.ATTESO.DEL.SISTEMA..SAS..)
names(G_G1_df) <- c("day", "Immesso","Riconsegnato", "SAS")

#Melt time series
G_G1_df=melt(G_G1_df,id.vars = "day")

#Create group variable
G_G1_df$group<- ifelse(G_G1_df$variable == "SAS", "SAS", "Immesso/Consegnato")

#plot
ggplot(G_G1_df, aes(as.Date(day),as.numeric(value),col=variable))+geom_point()+geom_line()+facet_wrap(~group,ncol=1,scales="free_y")+labs(x="Month", y="Values") +scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%m-%Y"))+geom_abline(intercept=c(-2,0,2),slope=0,data=subset(G_G1_df,group=="SAS"),lwd=0.5,lty=2)
```

Comment: not sure if it solves your problem. `make.names()` is designed to make names that R "like". If you can use this function on the sheetnames ...

Comment: The problem might be in reading the files. You could try the `read_excel()` function from the readxl package instead.

Comment: What about using the sheet index instead of sheet name?

Comment: thanks guys. since i am not attached to the sheet names, i am gonna look at indexing..